# awk keep column value 0 when two columns have value 0

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have infile.txt file with multiple columns and rows like this:

infile.txt

```
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  979  0        282.6  284.3  285.4  0     0
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  925  469.578  290.4  296.9  297.7  3.6   5.1
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  909  613.987  290.8  298.8  299.5  4.7   3.3
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  850  1169.4   288    301.6  303.1  9.3   0
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  700  2776.28  279    308.9  309.6  0     7.1
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  500  5561.01  258.1  314.6  314.8  14.2  11.9
```

and, I want to perform some column-based calculation as follows:

```
awk '{R=0; if($12) R=(('$g'/'$theta_vs')*($11-'$theta_vs')*($8-'$z_s'))/(($12^2)+($13^2)); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,R }' > test.txt
```

This work perfect and keep R=0 when $12!=0 but this provides an output value 0 when $12==0 as follows:

outputfile:

```
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  979  0        282.6  284.3  285.4  0     0     0
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  925  469.578  290.4  296.9  297.7  3.6   5.1   5.08926
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  909  613.987  290.8  298.8  299.5  4.7   3.3   9.01363
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  850  1169.4   288    301.6  303.1  9.3   0     8.21755
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  700  2776.28  279    308.9  309.6  0     7.1   0
2020  01  13  00  28.5833  77.2000  500  5561.01  258.1  314.6  314.8  14.2  11.9  16.3555
```

I want to keep R=0 when both $12 && $13 is 0.

How can I make it?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use unquoting to access shell variables in `awk`. Turn them into awk variables with the `-v` option.

Comment: I have a script of more than 500 lines for and these variables are used frequently and the value of these variables vary each time. Therefore I kept those outsides of a  line to avoid confusion.

Comment: What's confusing about `awk -v g=$g -v theta_vs=$theta_vs`?

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v G="$g" -v theta="$theta_vs" -v z="$z_s" '{R=0; if($12 || $13) R=((G/theta)*($11-theta)*($8-z))/(($12^2)+($13^2)); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,R }' Input_file
```

In case your lines have only 13 fields then as per Ed sir's suggestion adding following.

```
awk -v G="$g" -v theta="$theta_vs" -v z="$z_s" '{R=0; if($12 || $13) R=((G/theta)*($11-theta)*($8-z))/(($12^2)+($13^2)); print $0,R }' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
if ($12)
```

to

```
if ($12 || $13)
```

This will assign `R` if either of them is non-zero, and leave it at `0` if both of them are zero.